# Нижнее подчеркивание для заголовка

Tags: html, css

Вот обычный заголовок с подчеркиванием

```css
.promo_title h1 {
    display: inline;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.promo_title h1:after {
    content: "";
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo_title">
  <h1>Мужская коллекция</h1>
</div>
```

При ресайзе получается вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так чтобы нижнее подчеркивание было под двумя словами всегда?

Comment: А надо-то как??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет лучше тем, что не будет зависимости от того, какой фон:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.body:before,
.body:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.body:before {
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.body:after {
  right: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.promo_title {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c2c2c;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px transparent, inset 0 -1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
<div class="promo_title">
  <h1>Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать использовать `box-shadow`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c2c2c;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow:
  inset 0 -0.175em white,
  inset 0 -0.2em #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="promo_title">
  <h1>Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция</h1>
</div>
```

Можно использовать `text-decoration`
`text-decoration-skip-ink : none` будет перекрывать текст, если убрать, то букву 
`Ц` подчёркивание будет обходить

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2c2c2c;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dashed;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none; // подчеркивание будет перекрывать текст
}
```

```html
<h1>Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция Мужская коллекция</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно что-бы выглядело вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уменьшите font-size: 36px; до 25-30.

Comment: А надписи могут быть разные.

Comment: Неужели единственный способ это через регулярку оборачивать каждое слово в span и тегу span задавать нижнее подчеркивание?

Comment: Не совсем вас понял. Для чего использовать регулярку?
По поводу надписей, поясните. Если на разных страницах разные надписи - проще всего будет задать для каждой свой класс

Answer (score 0):

Используйте тег `<u></u>`

```html
<h1><u>Мужская одежда</u></h1>
```